# What's the best site/book to a J2SE programmer start to study J2ME?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I'm a J2SE programmer from 3 years, and I would like to start studing about J2ME, which is the best site/book to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470743182) because it is recent for a J2ME book and because using a Symbian device for your first development efforts will have the huge advantage of being easily able to use Exception stack traces to find problems.

You will want to look into resources directly from [Sun/Oracle](http://java.sun.com/javame/index.jsp) and the [JCP](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/platform?listBy=1&listByType=platform).

[Sony-Ericsson](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/technology/java/sdk) and [Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Java/) have invested huge amounts in developing J2ME technologies.